# How to effectively update all Landing Pages after changing their template in Marketo?

Tags: templates, auto-update, updating, marketo, automatic-updates

After changing and approving the template in Marketo, I must also approve the change in all associated Landing Pages.

**The only way I know to do this is manually open and approve each of these Landing Pages separately...**

**Is there any way to update (approve) all Landing Pages at one time, which are associated with the changed template?**

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

**After changing and approving the template**, go to ***"Design Studio"*** and click on the branch ***"Landing Pages"***:

[image]

In the view that appears, in the ***"Last Updated"*** column, set the sorting to ***"Sort Descending"***:

[image]

Then all **Landing Pages, which are associated with the previously modified and approved template will be displayed first**:

[image]

you can **select as many rows as you need**:

[image]

and in ***"Landing Page Actions"*** menu item, apply for them ***"Approve Draft"*** option:

[image]

#### Hint:

By clicking on ***"Select All"*** we **select all rows on all pages**, not just on the one that appears:

[image]

#### Warning:

Be sure to act on the **appropriate Landing Pages. After approval, all changes will be visible immediately.**

#### Source:

[Source and inspiration](https://nation.marketo.com/thread/29040) of the **solution**.

Comment: Amazingly, once again I wrote a question on StackOverflow, I was able to quickly find a solution for a given problem. I hope that this solution, along with screenshots prepared by me, will help someone :)

Comment: This method really saves a lot of time compared to the one described in the question...